# MedusaJs with strapi default command run error - ApplicationError: The type is required

Tags: strapi, medusajs

I am setting up medusaJS with Strapi by default command https://docs.medusajs.com/plugins/cms/strapi

I did setup Redis, medusa cli, was using Node version 16,18. However, I got this issue

```
Now using node v18.13.0 (npm v8.19.3)
❯ npx create-strapi-app strapi-medusa --template shahednasser/strapi-medusa-template
? Choose your installation type Quickstart (recommended)
Creating a quickstart project.
Creating a new Strapi application at /Users/felixle/Downloads/6github_new/strapi-medusa.
Creating files.
Installing strapi-medusa-template template.
Dependencies installed successfully.
Initialized a git repository.


Your application was created at /Users/felixle/Downloads/6github_new/strapi-medusa.

Available commands in your project:

  yarn develop
  Start Strapi in watch mode. (Changes in Strapi project files will trigger a server restart)

  yarn start
  Start Strapi without watch mode.

  yarn build
  Build Strapi admin panel.

  yarn strapi
  Display all available commands.

You can start by doing:

  cd /Users/felixle/Downloads/6github_new/strapi-medusa
  yarn develop

Running your Strapi application.

> strapi-medusa@0.1.0 develop
> strapi develop

Building your admin UI with development configuration...
Admin UI built successfully
ApplicationError: The type is required
    at getFieldSize (/Users/felixle/Downloads/6github_new/strapi-medusa/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-content-manager/server/services/field-sizes.js:57:15)
    at getDefaultFieldSize (/Users/felixle/Downloads/6github_new/strapi-medusa/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-content-manager/server/services/utils/configuration/layouts.js:34:10)
    at appendToEditLayout (/Users/felixle/Downloads/6github_new/strapi-medusa/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-content-manager/server/services/utils/configuration/layouts.js:139:27)
    at createDefaultEditLayout (/Users/felixle/Downloads/6github_new/strapi-medusa/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-content-manager/server/services/utils/configuration/layouts.js:56:10)
    at createDefaultLayouts (/Users/felixle/Downloads/6github_new/strapi-medusa/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-content-manager/server/services/utils/configuration/layouts.js:40:11)
    at createDefaultConfiguration (/Users/felixle/Downloads/6github_new/strapi-medusa/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-content-manager/server/services/utils/configuration/index.js:26:20)
    at async generateNewConfiguration (/Users/felixle/Downloads/6github_new/strapi-medusa/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-content-manager/server/services/configuration.js:53:36)
    at async Promise.all (index 13)
    at async Object.syncConfigurations (/Users/felixle/Downloads/6github_new/strapi-medusa/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-content-manager/server/services/configuration.js:67:5)
    at async module.exports [as bootstrap] (/Users/felixle/Downloads/6github_new/strapi-medusa/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-content-manager/server/bootstrap.js:7:3) {
  details: {}
}
```

Could you please help me?

Thanks

The project can run

Comment: i am facing same error, did you solved it ?

Comment: Did either you or @HERAwais find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4):

As others have suggested, it has nothing to do with the source code of medusa per se. The problem you're getting is a missing type field in a schema.

This part of the code, where you are getting the error from, parses the schema.json files in the content-types folders under src/api/[content-type-name]/content-types/[content-type-name]. You will notice with the specific template you've chosen that not all attributes in this schema.json files have a type field.

Strapi v4 introduced major changes in its schema structures. Some of the migrations to v4 can be applied automatically as it happened with shahednasser/strapi-medusa-template. But some are manually, which weren't applied to that directory. You need to migrate the rest of the changes in the schema files to Strapi v4s new format and everything should work.

Just for reference, here is a snippet from the payment-provider content-type in v3 and then v4

v3:

```
"regions": {
      "via": "payment_providers",
      "collection": "region"
    }
```

v4:

```
"regions": {
      "type": "relation",
      "relation": "manyToMany",
      "target": "api::region.region",
      "inversedBy": "payment_providers"
    }
```

Some people did this already, so I took the schema files from [this](https://github.com/Deathwish98/strapi-medusa-template) repository and wrote a simple Python script to replace all the files from the mentioned repository to the template from shahednasser:

```
import os
import shutil

# Define the source directory where the new schema.json files are located
source_dir = "src/api"

# Define the target directory where the existing schema.json files are located which should be replaced
target_dir = "strapi-medusa/src/api"

# Iterate over all the subdirectories in the target directory
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(target_dir):
    for file in files:
        # Check if the current file is a schema.json file
        if file == "schema.json":
            # Define the path to the current schema.json file
            current_file_path = os.path.join(subdir, file)

            # Extract the name of the content-type
            content_type_name = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(subdir)))

            # Define the path to the new schema.json file
            new_file_path = os.path.join(source_dir, content_type_name, "content-types", content_type_name, file)

            # Check if the new schema.json file exists
            if os.path.exists(new_file_path):
                # Replace the current schema.json file with the new one
                shutil.copy(new_file_path, current_file_path)
                print(f"Replaced {current_file_path} with {new_file_path}")
```

If you have any further Questions, I'm happy to answer them.

EDIT: Made the issue and what has to be done a little bit clearer.

Comment: I tried this fix, and it works for the most part, however something seems to be wrong with the product variants. If I create a new product variant, it is added to strapi, but the relation between the product and the product variant is not made. If I then delete the product variant in medusa, it is not deleted (nor updated) in strapi. One thing I found out is that the url /api/product-variants/<strapi or medusa id> will always return 404 not found, which is weird...

Answer (score 0):

We cannot resolve it from our side because it is from the source code of Medusa.

I format the data by a function, then import the result into postgres DB.

```html
const fs = require('fs');

// Function to format a single item
// Function to format a single item
const formatDbItem = (product) => {
  const result = {
    title: product.title,
    subtitle: null,
    description: product.body_html,
    handle: product.handle,
    weight: 0,
    is_giftcard: false,
    images: product.images.map((image) => image.src),
    options: product.options.map((option) => ({
      title: option.name,
      values: [option.values].flat(), // Flatten the values array
    })),
    variants: product.variants.map((variant) => {
      const variantObj = {
        title: variant.title,
        // data of prices should be in an array
        prices: [
          {
            currency_code: 'cad',
            amount: Math.floor(parseInt(variant.price) * 100),
          },
          {
            currency_code: 'usd',
            amount: Math.floor(parseInt(variant.price) * 100 * 1.25),
          },
          {
            currency_code: 'eur',
            amount: Math.floor(parseInt(variant.price) * 100 * 1.5),
          },
        ],
        options: Object.keys(variant)
          .filter((key) => key.startsWith('option'))
          .map((key) => {
            const value = variant[key];
            if (value !== null) {
              return { value };
            }
          })
          .filter(Boolean), // Filter out undefined values
        inventory_quantity: variant.inventory_quantity,
        manage_inventory: true,
      };
      return variantObj;
    }),
  };
  return result;
};

// Read the contents of productsShopify.json
const originalData = fs.readFileSync('data/productsShopify.json');
const jsonData = JSON.parse(originalData);
// Apply formatDbItem function to each item
const formattedData = jsonData.products.map(formatDbItem);

// Write the modified data to a new JSON file
fs.writeFileSync('data/formattedProducts.json', JSON.stringify(formattedData));
```

So, if you need more help please inform me.

Best wish

Answer (score 0):

I made a fork which should fix this issue (and some other issues as well). You can find it here:

https://github.com/thomcrielaard/strapi-medusa-template.git

If you have any issues feel free to report them! :)